# Java: CyclicBarrier not working

Tags: java, multithreading, loops, cycle, barrier

The soft should do some calculus: 62500 loops in total and one loop duration is 0.5 sec. That would be ~ 8 hours of work (for in for in for). I must divide into 100 separate threads and the work time would be reduced to 8 min of work. I can't open 62500 threads because the CPU, I must find a solution to open only 100 threads than again 100. I tried with CountDownLatch but I can't reset the cycle, so my solution would be CyclicBarrier.

```
private CycleBarrier cb;

// this Overrided run is called only once from the view to not block the UI.
@Override
public void run(){

   // count is the number of the actions that i want to do
   // this is why I'm using CycleBarrier
   for(int count = 0; count < 2; count++){
      System.out.println("MAIN THREAD: #"+count);

      int x1 = 0;
      cb = new CycleBarrier(100, new Runnable(){
         @Override
         public void run(){
            // HOW TO STOP CYCLE ???
         }
      });

      for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
         new Thread(new Test(x1, cb)).start();
         x1 += 25;
      }
   }
}
```

And the **Test** class

```
public class Test implements Runnable{

   int x1;
   CycleBarrier cb;

   public Test(int _x1, CycleBarrier _cb){
      x1 = _x1;
      cb = _cb;
   }

   @Override
   public void run(){
      // this for in for has 6250 loops
      for(int i = x1; < x1+25; i++){
         for(int j = 0; j < 250; j++){
            System.out.println("   |--> LOOK I'm WORKING: "+i+" "+j);
         }
      }

      // After the job is done, it should be put in to await
      cb.await();
   }
}
```

The cycle not working. It's opening 200 at once. I tried to debug (eclipse) but I don't know why, the Thread jump from one to another, I can't follow the result.

The console should look like:

```
MAIN THREAD: #0
   LOOK I'm WORKING: 0 0
   LOOK I'm WORKING: 0 1
   ...
   LOOK I'm WORKING: 25 254
   LOOK I'm WORKING: 25 255

MAIN THREAD: #1
   LOOK I'm WORKING: 0 0
   LOOK I'm WORKING: 0 1
   ...
   LOOK I'm WORKING: 25 254
   LOOK I'm WORKING: 25 255
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Why it's opening 200 thread at once instead of 100?

Answer (score 0):

```
cb = new CycleBarrier(100, new Runnable(){
@Override
 public void run(){
        // HOW TO STOP CYCLE ???
     }
  });

  for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
     new Thread(new Test(x1, cb)).start();
     x1 += 25;
  }
```

In your code you are opening a new Thread Object inside a new Runnable. So there are two threads.